# call mysql_library_end after mysql_close but segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, c

After reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-library-end.html, I try to call `mysql_library_end()` after `mysql_close()` when finishing a query. However, when I need to query again, I get a segmentation fault when calling `mysql_real_connect()`. What I do is just connect twice:

```
MYSQL *mysql;
mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, host, user, passwd, db, 3306, NULL, 0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "connect failed\n");
}
mysql_close(mysql);
mysql_library_end();

mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, host, user, passwd, db, 3306, NULL, 0)) // segmentation fault here
{
    fprintf(stderr, "connect failed\n");
}
mysql_close(mysql);
mysql_library_end();
```

gdb backtrace:

```
#0 phtread_mutex_lock
#1 yaSSL::Sessions::lookup
#2 yaSSL::yaSSL_get_session
#3 ssl_do
#4 ssl_connect
#5 cli_establish_ssl
#6 mysql_real_connect 
#7 main
```

If I do not call `mysql_library_end()`, the program runs well but valgrind says some memories are still reachable after `mysql_close()`. What should I do to fix the program without memory leak? My mysql version is 5.7.19. Thank you for your visit and response!

Comment: From the documentation: "In a nonmulti-threaded environment, the call to `mysql_library_init()` may be omitted". Are you in a nonmulti-threaded environment? (seen the trace, I don't think so)

Comment: I'm sure that the program is in a nonmulti-threaded environment. The documentation says that mysql_library_init() should be called before spawning any threads in multi-threaded environment, but don't say what should I do in a nonmulti-threaded environment. I just use mysql_init() which call mysql_library_init() automatically as necessary. Thank you anyway! @purplepsycho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this" issue--the answer is don't call mysql_library_end().  The fact that valgrind reports that it is still hanging on to some memory after you are done is not a bug--it just means that it allocated some memory and it hasn't freed it yet because it isn't done with it.

It probably shouldn't segfault if you do call mysql_library_end() followed by another mysql_init(), but the man page does say that you only call mysql_library_end() when you are done using the library, so the action when you try to use the library after calling it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I mean what you say, but valgrind shows that memories which are still reachable increase with the increment of the number of connections. Why memories used by connection didn't free after mysql_close? I am worried that if the program runs for a long time it will run out of memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand--what kind of connections are we talking about?  You can't be doing database connections without using the mysql library.  Why do you think the memory is being used by the mysql library instead of elsewhere?  If your program is adding connections, it is going to use more memory to support them; and reachable memory is generally not a problem.  When the connections go away, and then new ones come in, does memory use continue to increase or does it remain largely static?  Valgrind is a useful tool, but you can make yourself crazy chasing nonissues with it also.

Comment: The connections just mean database connections. After two database connections close(call mysql_close without mysql_library_end), memories that are still reachable are twice as much as just one database connection. Anyway, may be you are right and I shouldn't chasing nonissues. The document of valgrind also says that still reachable is not very serious. Thank you.